# Install iOSOpenDev with Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, jailbreak

I am getting errors:

> File not found
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Specifications/iPhoneOSPackageTypes.xcspec

After checking the dir structure of Xcode 7 (7.2 in my case), i found no "Specifications" subdir in the path. Looks like Xcode has either changed the location or it does not allow customized package types anymore?

Answer (score 0):

I went through the original iOSOpenDev's installation wiki and found out for Xcode 7.2 and found out that we can manually create the directory and copy the files over. In the end, iOSOpenDev is up and running with Xcode 7.2:
[image]

Here are the steps:
0) Install iOSOpenDev normally and follow the usual steps. Once the installation is done conduct the following steps 1) and 2).

1. Create Specifications DIR on this path:
   `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Specifications`
2. Create the following files using a text editor under Specifications DIR:

   ```
    iPhoneOSPackageTypes.xcspec:
    (
       { 
           Type = PackageType; 
           Identifier = com.apple.package-type.mach-o-executable; 
           Name = "Mach-O Executable"; 
           Description = "Mach-O executable"; 
           DefaultBuildSettings = { 
               EXECUTABLE_PREFIX = ""; 
               EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX = ""; 
               EXECUTABLE_NAME = "$(EXECUTABLE_PREFIX)$(PRODUCT_NAME)$(EXECUTABLE_VARIANT_SUFFIX)$(EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX)"; 
               EXECUTABLE_PATH = "$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)"; 
           }; 
           ProductReference = { 
               FileType = compiled.mach-o.executable; Name = "$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)"; 
               IsLaunchable = YES; 
           }; 
       }
       { 
           Type = PackageType; 
           Identifier = com.apple.package-type.mach-o-dylib; 
           Name = "Mach-O Dynamic Library"; 
           Description = "Mach-O dynamic library"; 
           DefaultBuildSettings = { 
               EXECUTABLE_PREFIX = ""; 
               EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX = ""; 
               EXECUTABLE_NAME = "$(EXECUTABLE_PREFIX)$(PRODUCT_NAME)$(EXECUTABLE_VARIANT_SUFFIX)$(EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX)"; 
               EXECUTABLE_PATH = "$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)"; 
           }; 
           ProductReference = { 
               FileType = compiled.mach-o.dylib; 
               Name = "$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)"; IsLaunchable = NO; 
           }; 
       }
   )

   iPhoneOSProductTypes.xcspec:  

   (
       { 
           Type = ProductType; 
           Identifier = com.apple.product-type.tool; 
           Class = PBXToolProductType; 
           Name = "Command-line Tool"; 
           Description = "Standalone command-line tool"; 
           IconNamePrefix = "TargetExecutable"; 
           DefaultTargetName = "Command-line Tool"; 
           DefaultBuildProperties = { 
               FULL_PRODUCT_NAME = "$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)"; 
               EXECUTABLE_PREFIX = ""; 
               EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX = ""; 
               REZ_EXECUTABLE = YES; 
               INSTALL_PATH = "/usr/bin"; 
               FRAMEWORK_FLAG_PREFIX = "-framework"; 
               LIBRARY_FLAG_PREFIX = "-l"; 
               LIBRARY_FLAG_NOSPACE = YES; 
               GCC_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC = NO; 
               GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN = YES; 
               GCC_INLINES_ARE_PRIVATE_EXTERN = YES; 
               STRIP_STYLE = "all"; 
               CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED = YES; 
               ENTITLEMENTS_ALLOWED = YES; 
               MACH_O_TYPE = "mh_execute"; 
           }; 
           PackageTypes = (com.apple.package-type.mach-o-executable); 
       }
       { 
           Type = ProductType; Identifier = com.apple.product-type.library.dynamic; 
           Class = PBXDynamicLibraryProductType; 
           Name = "Dynamic Library"; 
           Description = "Dynamic library"; 
           IconNamePrefix = "TargetLibrary"; 
           DefaultTargetName = "Dynamic Library"; 
           DefaultBuildProperties = { 
               FULL_PRODUCT_NAME = "$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)"; 
               MACH_O_TYPE = "mh_dylib"; 
               REZ_EXECUTABLE = YES; 
               EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX = ".$(EXECUTABLE_EXTENSION)"; 
               EXECUTABLE_EXTENSION = "dylib"; 
               PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH = "/usr/include"; 
               PRIVATE_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH = "/usr/include"; 
               INSTALL_PATH = "/usr/lib"; 
               DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME_BASE = "$(INSTALL_PATH)"; 
               LD_DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME = "$(DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME_BASE:standardizepath)/$(EXECUTABLE_PATH)"; 
               DYLIB_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION = "1"; 
               DYLIB_CURRENT_VERSION = "1"; 
               FRAMEWORK_FLAG_PREFIX = "-framework"; 
               LIBRARY_FLAG_PREFIX = "-l"; 
               LIBRARY_FLAG_NOSPACE = YES; 
               STRIP_STYLE = "debugging"; 
               GCC_INLINES_ARE_PRIVATE_EXTERN = YES; 
               CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED = YES; 
           }; 
           PackageTypes = (com.apple.package-type.mach-o-dylib); 
       }
   )
   ```

This should fix the problem.